# Get sidebar parameters (before_widget, before_title, etc.) from within a widget

Tags: widgets, sidebar, register-sidebar

Is it possible to dynamically get sidebar parameters from within a widget? That is, I am trying to access the `before_widget`/`after_widget`/`before_title`/`after_title`/`name` parameters of the containing sidebar.

Suppose we have a sidebar registered like so:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => "Homepage Sidebar",
    'id' => 'homepage-sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>',
) );
```

How would I access those values from inside my widget's `widget()` function? Like, how would I do something like this:

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    // outputs the content of the widget
    if ($someCondition)
        echo $sidebar->before_title . 'My widget title' . $sidebar->before_title;
    echo 'You are looking at ' . $sidebar->name;
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters are given (as an array) as the first argument provided to the `widget` method. The second argument, `$instance`, holds the options for that particular instance of the widget.

My usual set up is:

```
 function widget($args, $instance){
    //Extract the widget-sidebar parameters from array
    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

    echo $before_widget;
    echo $before_title;
    //Display title as stored in this instance of the widget
    echo esc_html($instance['title']); 
    echo $after_title;
    //Widget content
    echo $after_widget;

 }
```

Comment: As far as I understood the question, the OP wants to have data from the `sidebar`, not the widget.

Comment: Yes me too - that is what the `$args` are (also includes widget ID and widget name), whereas `$instance` are the widget options. See [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4/wp-includes/widgets.php#L870) (`$sidebar` contains the data from `register_sidebar`)

Answer (score -1):

Use variable name only, like:

```
$name
$before_title
$after_title
$before_widget
$after_widget
```

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted... it's actually correct.

Comment: Because it got no further explanation. Stumbled upon it, when the system flagged it as "low quality" i guess - made dozens of up-/downvotes yesterday to get flags done. If you edit something and leave me a comment, I'll remove the downvote.